# How do you properly state that you like the pant(s) you are currently wearing?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

My husband and I were discussing this about a week ago and it has been on my mind ever since.

Would you say "I like these types of pants", "I like this type of pant", or "I like these types of pant" to express that you like the style of pants you are currently wearing?

We asked our friends and they were just as baffled as we were.

Thanks!

Comment: Why *pant* in the singular? Is that a common way to refer to them in the US? I get the *...this type of..* vs *...these type of...* vs *...these types of...* But "pants" vs "pant"? It's *pants* all the way!

Comment: I felt like the type of pant and types of pants was more consistent. Then, I felt really confused about which was correct.

Comment: Which sounds better: (a) "What type of scissor", (b) "What types of scissors" or (c) "What type of scissors"?

Comment: Why ***type*** at all? If it’s the pants you’re wearing: “I like these pants!” or if it’s the style: “I like pants like these.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "I like this type of pants", since I assume that you are expressing preference for a single type. If you're holding a pair of jeans in one hand and a pair of khakis in the other, then you could say "I like these types of pants". The only time I have heard the singular word "pant" used is in the term "pant leg".

NB: "pants" means something very different in the UK than it does in the US!

Comment: I just looked it up. That must be awkward for anyone reading from the UK.